# Import a single constant

Tags: swift, import

The [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) says I can import a value using `import [kind]`, and that I have the options `typealias`,­ `struct`,­ `class`,­ `enum`,­ `protocol­`, `var`, and­ `func`. So I can import *e* for example, like this:

```
import var Glibc.M_E
```

But this imports `M_E` as a `var` variable. How do I import `M_E` as a `let` constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other "simple" C macros, the definition

```
#define M_E         2.71828182845904523536028747135266250   /* e              */
```

from `<math.h>` is imported to Swift as a global *read-only* computed property:

```
public var M_E: Double { get } /* e              */
```

It is a `var`, but you cannot change its value:

```
print(M_E) // OK
M_E = 2.0 // error: cannot assign to value: 'M_E' is a get-only property
```